# Implementation specifics wrt adding a ROS 2 node to a Gazebo Sim system plugin

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugin

In the ROSCon 2022 presentation on [ROS 2 and Gazebo Integration Best Practices](https://vimeo.com/showcase/9954564/video/767127300#t=912s), one of the proposed options is to embed a ROS 2 node into a Gazebo Sim System.

The slides propose to add following section in `Configure()`:

```cpp
if(!rclcpp::ok()) {
  rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);
}
```

and then to create a node and publisher/subscriber/etc as required.

So far so good, but where and how to spin the node?

I think this could work by:

- Also creating an Executor in the `Configure()` step,
- Adding the node to it,
- Calling `executor_.spin_some()` in the `preUpdate()` step,
- Or alternatively: `spin_once()`? Or `spin_all()`?
- Those functions optionally take a time-out value.

  I assume in my case this is not relevant as the node will not be doing extensive work (only publishing and subscribing to some data)?

I would be inclined to go with a `spin_all()` as that makes sure everything gets processed, but I am not sure if that is best-practice.

And then to stop the ROS node at the end, I think the following is needed in the system plugin's destructor:

```cpp
executor_.cancel();
rclcpp::shutdown();
```

Is that correct, or am I still missing something?